# Create a single worktree in git which has multiple projects

Tags: git, github

I am very new to command line git and I have this below task assigned:

We have multiple repositories in our project. Now we want to come up with a single repository to have everything in one tree.

Now there is Project1 which has A,B,C,D,E files - Project2 has A,C,E files - Project3 has A,B,C,D files. Also file A(like a make file) has different content in project1, project2 and project3

So the idea is to have all the files in one worktree and when we do a git clone for Project2 for example it should get only those files and the A file with right content.

Please let me know how can I achieve this using git or any other way?
Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: What you're trying to do is called a monorepo. Basically, you just set all your project directories at the root directory of the repo. When you clone, you clone everything and you just have to `cd Project2` to go in a project. The goal of monorepo is to actually have everything in one place. Here some lecture about it https://github.com/korfuri/awesome-monorepo and https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/monorepos

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Yes we are trying to have a monorepo. I wanted to know if we can achieve the above scenario when we have a monorepo.

Comment: There's one solution sparse-checkout I found on internet to get only files we want. But if same file with different content is used in different project, can i do a git clone so I get the right file with right content?